# term by term differentiation of $\sum_{n \geq 1} \arctan \frac {x} {n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading a book and found a question "analyze the applicability of term by term differentiation for $\sum_{n \geq 1} \arctan \frac {x} {n^2}$", What does that means? How to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @Ethan: I think what is asked is to justify $\frac{d}{dx}(\sum\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{n^2})=\sum\frac{d}{dx}(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{n^2})$

Comment: @Shahab I'm not sure that's relevant. I believe you are saying that you can differentiate a power series by differentiating its terms one at a time. But OP's function is not a power series, and not clearly analytic. (Or is it?) And if OP's function is analytic, these terms are not the terms of its power series.

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to investigate whether or not $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\ge1}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{d}{dx}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$$ I believe that answers your first question. Your second question is how to accomplish this. But now that the first is more clear, you might have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that, the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^4+x^2}, $$

which is the derivative of our original series, converges uniformly $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, since

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^4+x^2}  \leq  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} <\infty .$$

That implies we can differentiate the series term by term. There are other verifications you should take in consideration. See  [theorem 2, page 1](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf) .