# For which x function f is continuous and for which is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ f(x) =  \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan(n + x)}{n^2+x^2} $$

For which x function f is continuous and for which is differentiable?
if $f'(0) $ exists than does $f'(0)>0$?

Comment: $|f(x)|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$ so the series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360967/term-by-term-differentiation-of-sum-n-geq-1-arctan-frac-x-n2).

Answer (score 1):

Since $|\arctan y|<{\pi\over2}$ for all real $y$ it follows that the termwise differentiated series 
$$\Sigma'(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{-2x\arctan(n+x)\over(n^2+x^2)^2}+{1\over\bigl(1+(n+x)^2\bigr)(n^2+x^2)}$$
 is uniformly convergent on any compact interval. Therefore $f$ is everywhere differentiable, and $f'(x)$ is given by $\Sigma'(x)$. In particular it follows that $f'(0)>0$.