# A tricky term-by-term differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\{q_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in the unit interval $[0,1]$. Let $\{a_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ be positive real numbers with $\textstyle\sum_j a_j < \infty$. Define for all $x\in [0,1]$
$$g(x):=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \,a_j \sqrt[3]{x-q_j}.$$
It is claimed in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative) wiki page that
$$g^{\prime}(x)=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a_j}{\sqrt[3]{(x-q_j)^2}}$$
holds at any point $x$ where the sum is finite.

It is not clear to me how to justify this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your question how to justify term-by-term differentiation in general, i.e. why $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{j=0}^\infty f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty f'(x)$$ in general when both sums exist?

Comment: @AlexBecker: No, my question is how to justify this particular differentiation.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360967/term-by-term-differentiation-of-sum-n-geq-1-arctan-frac-x-n2).

Comment: "Where the sum is finite"? The summands are nonzero almost everywhere, hence we never have a finite sum, always a series

Comment: "The sum is finite" means that the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

First,
$$
  g'(x)
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h}
= \lim_{h \to 0}\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{g_j(x+h) - g_j(x)}{h}
$$
where $g_j(x) := a_j(x-q_j)^{1/3}$. It should be clear that 
$$
  g_j'(x)
= \frac{a_j}{3(x-q_j)^{2/3}},
$$
and so all that is needed is to justify swapping the order of the limits. But consider $\mu$ the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$: the limit can be written as
$$
  g'(x)
= \lim_{m \to \infty} \int s_m(j) d\mu(j)
$$
where
$$
   s_m(j)
:= \frac{g_j(x+1/m) - g_j(x)}{1/m}.
$$
For a fixed $j$, $\lim_{m \to \infty} s_m(j) = g_j'(x)$, and this is finite since $[0,1]$ is closed. Also,
$$
  \int g_j'(x) d\mu(j)
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a_j}{3(x-q_j)^{2/3}}
< \infty.
$$
Thus the sequence $\{s_m\}$ is eventually dominated by an integrable function, and the dominated convergence theorem can be employed to conclude
$$
  g'(x)
= \int \lim_{m \to \infty} s_m(j) d\mu(j) 
= \int g'_j(x) d\mu(j)
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a_j}{3(x-q_j)^{2/3}}.
$$

Comment: What is the dominating function for $s_m$? Why is it integrable?

Comment: Since $\lim_{m \to \infty} s_m(j) = g_j'(x) < \infty$, you can let $M$ be large enough so that $m \geq M$ implies $s_m(j) \leq g_j'(x) + 2^{-j}$. This is an integrable function which eventually dominates $\{s_m\}$ therefore. It is integrable by the hypothesis that the sum is finite. 
Also, I'd appreciate a comment from whoever downvoted.

Comment: Presumably $M$ will depend on $j$ though.